# mysql different query share one index

Tags: mysql

I have 2 queries

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE store_id=1 && album_id=1 && delete=0
UPDATE table SET delete=0 WHERE store_id=1 && album_id=1
```

I create an index `store_id, album_id, delete`

my question is can these 2 queries share this index?

or I have to create another index (store_id, album_id) for 2nd one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are creating one index that is a composite index as `table(store_id, album_id, delete)`, then both queries should be able to use this index.

THe first will use all three fields in the index because they match the `where` clause exactly.

The second query will use the first two columns in the index for its `where` clause.